# Joda time zone calculation

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

Been playing around with Joda timezones and found the following which seemed odd.

I ran the following code

```
    DateTimeZone gmt = DateTimeZone.forID( "Etc/GMT" );
    DateTimeZone gmtPlusOne = DateTimeZone.forID( "Etc/GMT+1" );
    DateTimeZone gmtMinusOne = DateTimeZone.forID( "Etc/GMT-1" );

    System.out.println( new DateTime( gmt ).toString() );
    System.out.println( new DateTime( gmtPlusOne ).toString() );
    System.out.println( new DateTime( gmtMinusOne ).toString() );
```

And got the following output

```
2011-10-24T13:00:12.890Z
2011-10-24T12:00:12.937-01:00
2011-10-24T14:00:12.937+01:00
```

I was a bit suprised to see "gmtPlusOne" coming out as one hour behind with -01:00 and the reverse for "gmtMinusOne".  Can someone explain why these come out like this as I would have expected the opposite.

Comment: Don't worry Jon will be here any minute ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This [documentation](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/timezones.html) explains the reason for this not so intuitive behavior. It says `Etc/GMT+1` has a standard offset of `-1:00` and `Etc/GMT-1` has a standard offset of `+1:00`. This reversal of offset holds for any `Etc/GMT+n`.

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)

> The special area of Etc is used for some administrative zones,
>   particularly for "Etc/UTC" which represents Coordinated Universal
>   Time. In order to conform with the POSIX style, those zone names
>   beginning with "Etc/GMT" have their sign reversed from what most
>   people expect. In this style, zones west of GMT have a positive sign
>   and those east have a negative sign in their name (e.g "Etc/GMT-14" is
>   14 hours ahead/east of GMT.)

Comment: Apple discusses this POSIX issue in [this text file](http://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-230/zic.tproj/datfiles/etcetera). `We use POSIX-style signs in the Zone names and the output abbreviations, even though this is the opposite of what many people expect. POSIX has positive signs west of Greenwich, but many people expect positive signs east of Greenwich.  For example, TZ='Etc/GMT+4' uses the abbreviation "GMT+4" and corresponds to 4 hours behind UTC (i.e. west of Greenwich) even though many people would expect it to mean 4 hours ahead of UTC (i.e. east of Greenwich).`

Comment: These `Etc` should be unnecessary. Use a [proper time zone name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), usually a continent + slash + city/region such as `Asia/Kolkata` or `America/Montreal`.